# Tool to control windows network traffic (Internet Speed)

Tags: windows, gratis, networking, internet, connection-speed

I work on web development, therefore, in some rare situations I need to test our site and mimic different users' environments such as internet connection.  Because if the internet connection is very slow or not stable, un-noticed errors pop up (e.g. one js script loads before the other), ajax request got interrupted, validation request timeout etc.

So for that I want a program to run on Windows 7/8 (7&8 is what I use mainly)  to control the speed of the internet (transmission traffic).

Some of the features that I need:

Required:

1. Ability to adjust (limit) internet traffic for downloading.
2. <strike>Adjust traffic for the PC as a whole for all applications</strike>
3. <strike>To be free</strike>

Recommended but not required:

1. Adjust traffic (download + upload) for the whole system or for individual applications e.g. affect Firefox only, not Google Chrome.
2. Monitor traffic with summary of usage (how much data application X used in time N)
3. To be free (I only need this once every few month, so it's not worth it to buy a full license)

I've tried:

1. [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php) but I couldn't make it work for me.
2. [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) but the trial has a limited functionality, therefore I couldn't test slowing down connection speed.

**Most of the time I do my testing from localhost running XAMPP, so if the tool can control internal server speed that would be a big advantage.**

*To make this a bit more general and help fellow developers who got the same issue, you may mentioned as well a solution for other environments.*

**UPDATE [15-11-2014]**

I just noticed with the new updates to Google's Chrome Developers tool - under the emulation section an option to emulate mobile device internet speed such as WIFI or 3G. [More Details](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can it run in a VM?

Comment: I guess so, but what will be running on the VM? different OS? And then, would it affect programs outside of VM?

Comment: Basically you would need to load two VM instances... windows + (linux w/ [wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: Please specify the "brand" of "free": as in "free beer" (no cost), or as in "free speech" (open-source)?

Comment: @Izzy free beer, not necessarily open source :D 
I won't mind commercial or freemium as long as it suppresses the speed.

Comment: @MikePennington you can share if the tool you have in mind is available for Ubuntu, guess Linux users will benefits from this and I can manage boot from Ubuntu sometimes.

Comment: Would be interested to hear what was wrong with NetLimiter. I used to use that (until I stopped using Windows) and found it very effective

Answer (score 3):

[Promoting my comment to an answer...]

### WANEM - The Wide Area Network emulator

Controlling Windows bandwidth within Windows is tricky; however, if you build a virtual machine with the Windows webserver in it, then you can do much more with [wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/).

In your specific situation, you need:

- Windows VM with one virtual NIC
- Linux VM with two virtual NICs, (which would boot the [wanem iso](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/download.html))

Jeremy Stretch describes the details of [using wanem to control bandwidth / delay on his blog](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/jan/12/emulating-wans-wanem/)

### Other options

- [wansim](https://code.google.com/p/wansim/)
- Linux [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) module in the kernel

Answer (score 1):

I used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to simulate slow network speeds. At that time, I was using a Windows 7 box. However, at the bottom of the page, they since claim to support a variety of OSs (this covers the "other environments" suggestion).

By default, you have a preset to simulate "modem speeds". However, since Fiddler gives you access "under the hood", you can alter the corresponding scripts to further refine your experience. [This](http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/simulating-a-slow-connection-with-fiddler) tutorial is a good place to start.

Another check-mark on your list is the preference to be free.

I *think* you can set the speed caps per application, but I cannot recall now this detail, sorry.

As for the other points, I am afraid I wasn't particularly interested in those capabilities when I used it. You might want to check the supported plugins.

Answer (score 0):

[Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) is a nice portable application that can do network throttling as well as several other network traffic tampering operations.

[image: Clumsy animated gif]